# OracleParameter.ArrayBindSize is invalid, need some help on this issue

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm executing a Oracle stored procedure which has three output parameters and those are returning results in table format. I'm using array to capture those results. Here I'm getting this issue. Also kindly verify my stuff, does it make sense?

```
   Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("PKG_HOBS.PRC_HOBS_GET_CLIENTID", FPP1_Connection)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    Dim p1 As New OracleParameter(":obus_grp_id", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p1.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64
    p1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    p1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p1.Size = 100 ' This is the size of items in array in THIS case
    p1.ArrayBindSize = New Integer() {100}
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

    Dim p2 As New OracleParameter(":ostat_c", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p2.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64
    p2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    p2.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p2.Size = 100 ' This is the size of items in array in THIS case
    p2.ArrayBindSize = New Integer() {100}
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)

    Dim p3 As New OracleParameter(":ostat_msg_x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 500, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p3.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2
    p3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    p3.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p3.Size = 500 ' This is the size of items in array in THIS case
    p3.ArrayBindSize = New Integer() {500}
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3)

    FPP1_Connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this question. Hope it will help for some one. We have to use `Enumerable.repeat` for string data type.

```
     Dim cmd As New OracleCommand("PKG_HOBS.PRC_HOBS_GET_CLIENTID", FPP1_Connection)
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    'Passing three parameters and retriving the results in array
    Dim p1 As New OracleParameter("obus_grp_id", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p1.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p1.Size = 100
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1)

    Dim p2 As New OracleParameter("ostat_c", OracleDbType.Int64, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p2.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p2.Size = 100
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2)

    Dim p3 As New OracleParameter("ostat_msg_x", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
    p3.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
    p3.Size = 100
    p3.ArrayBindSize = Enumerable.Repeat(500, 100).ToArray 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(p3)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Try
        'Assigning each parameter values into local variables
        Dim oraobus_grp_id() As OracleDecimal = CType(p1.Value, OracleDecimal())
        Dim oraostat_c() As OracleDecimal = CType(p2.Value, OracleDecimal())
        Dim oraostat_msg_x() As OracleString = CType(p3.Value, OracleString())

        Dim obus_grp_idVal(oraobus_grp_id.Length - 1) As Long
        Dim ostat_cVal(oraostat_c.Length - 1) As Long
        Dim ostat_msg_xVal(oraostat_msg_x.Length - 1) As String

        For i As Integer = 0 To oraobus_grp_id.Length - 1
            obus_grp_idVal(i) = Convert.ToInt64(oraobus_grp_id(i).ToString)
            ostat_cVal(i) = Convert.ToInt64(oraostat_c(i).ToString)
            If ostat_cVal(i) <> "0" And ostat_cVal(i) <> "800" Then

                If Not oraostat_msg_x(i).IsNull Then
                    ostat_msg_xVal(i) = Convert.ToString(oraostat_msg_x(i).Value)
                    Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "", "Error response in new client retrieval: " + ostat_msg_xVal(i), "", 0)
                Else
                    ostat_msg_xVal(i) = Nothing
                    Dts.Events.FireError(-1, "", "Error response in new client retrieval: " + ostat_msg_xVal(i), "", 0)
                End If
            Else
                Call InsertClient(obus_grp_idVal(i))
            End If
        Next
```